# Add more to camera space but keep the perspective

Tags: rendering, camera

Let's say I made a model, set up light and camera, render size is 1024x1024

[image]

All of the sudden I need to add a second object that's outside the render boundary.

[image]

so I want to change my render settings so that both objects would fit in the render. But! I need to keep the perspective *and* pixel dimensions so that the first object would be exactly the same as on the original render.

If I simply change render width, the render boundary shrinks...

[image]

At the moment I create a duplicate of the active camera, shift it and render a second image to compose with the first one. Which isn't perfect for a lot of reasons. So I was wondering if there's a simpler solution?

[image]

Another solution would be using a wider camera angle, but in this case pixel dimensions of the original objects would change. I'd need probably to change render size accordingly but I don't know if there's a formula...

Comment: What you are searching for is called "overscan". You can find more information here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136352/how-to-render-over-camera-border-or-overscan If you are familiar with Python, here is an addon for 2.76 that should do the trick: https://github.com/sobotka/blender-addons-contrib/blob/master/camera_overscan.py

Comment: woah, thank you, I didn't know the term!